# why do i get "You already have a fork of this repository"?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

First off, I'm new to github!

I've cloned a project from `github` and made quite a few changes & extensions  to it. Now I want to push my changes but it says that I don't have the permissions. So I wanted to fork the project into my profile but I get "You already have a fork of this repository:" (which might be but I've deleted all my repos since, i.e. my profile now is empty:**You don’t have any repositories yet.**) How do I go about pushing my changes upstream?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new remote repository in github and then link it with your local one.

1. Create the repo in Github and copy the URL
2. Then, if the remote repository linked to your local one is called Origin (as usual). Do **git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/your-new-repo**
3. Do **git remote -v** to check that the change went ok
4. Now you can use **git push** to put all your changes upstream

Comment: Actually, this didn't work for me, now it wouldn't let me enter clean pull requests (to the original repo)... how can I get that going now?

Comment: What's the error? Maybe you don't have permission to create PR to that repo.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up deleteing my github account (as it was new and empty) and recreating a new account with the same name. I was then able to fork just fine, commit the changes from my disk, and open a pull reqest accordingly.